'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<TModel>.Model.get returned null.?
The debugger points the foreach section but I can't fix it. Where is the error?
My controller:
namespace Seminar5.Controllers
{
    public class SeminarController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Apply()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]

        public IActionResult Apply(UserInfo model)
        {
            Repository.CreateUser(model);
            
            return View("Thanks",model);
        }

        public IActionResult List()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return View(Repository.TakeId(id));
        }


My Model:
public class UserInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Phone { get; set; }
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    public bool WillAttend { get; set; }
}

My Repository:
public class Repository
    {
        private static List<UserInfo> _users = new();

        public static List<UserInfo> Users
        {
            get
            {
                return _users;
            }
        }

        static Repository()
        {
            _users.Add(new KullaniciBilgi() { Id = 1, Name = "Busra", Email = "blablabla@gmail.com", Phone = "111111111", WillAttend = true });
            _users.Add(new KullaniciBilgi() { Id = 2, Name = "Nur", Email = "blablabla@gmail.com", Phone = "8384388438", WillAttend = true });
            _users.Add(new KullaniciBilgi() { Id = 3, Name = "Busra", Email = "blablabla@gmail.com", Phone = "3438848384", WillAttend = true });
        }
       

        public static void CreateUser(UserInfo user)
        {
            _users.Add(user);
            user.Id = Users.Count + 1;
        }

       

        public static UserInfo? IdAl(int id)
        {
            return _users.FirstOrDefault(user => user.Id == id);
        }
    }
}


The .cshtml page and the foreach section that gives the "object reference..." error :
@model List<UserInfo>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Status of Participating Into Seminar";
}
<main class="text-center">
    <h1 class="h4">Seminar Participation List</h1>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>Participance Status</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @{
                int i = 0;
            }
            @foreach(var user in Model) 
            {
                var status = user.WillAttend == true ? "Evet" : "Hayır";
                var classname = user.WillAttend == true ? "table-success" : "table-danger";
                if(user.WillAttend==true)
                {
                    i++;
                    <tr class="@classname"></tr>
                    <td>@user.Name</td>
                    <td>@status</td>
                    <td>
                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="/seminer/details/@user.Id">Detail</a>
                    </td>
                }
            }

I tried to run it too many times, if you would like to help me I want to share with you in the comments if there are missing details or pages on the project that haven't been shared.

It's been a while sinece I dod some APS.NET MVC but you're passing KullaniciBilgi? when you do return View(Repository.IdAl(id)); but your view requests a model of type List<KullaniciBilgi>, pretty sure that's the problem. Either make your view take a model of type KullaniciBilgi? or pass a List<KullaniciBilgi> in your call to View

Also be aware of the race condition in your CreateUser method.

How are you injecting your Repository into your SeminerController?

I feel sorry for the Turkish class names, next time I'll fix the them into English to make them more understandable. "MindSwipe", May I ask how can I change my model into List? Because when I try, the system doesn't allow me to change the view into a list. For the second method, it didnt't work either. Can you explain more deeply?

"Fildor", how can I change the CreateUser method, it's written for the models.

"SoftwareDveloper", I am injecting my repository into SeminerController as :
public IActionResult Details(int id)
{
return View(Repository.IdAl(id));
}

Which controller throwing that error in particular? Have you checked that?


Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<TModel>.Model.get returned null.?
The debugger points the foreach section but I can't fix it. Where is the error?

Based on your shared code snippet and description the reason for your error is pretty obvious. The view you are loading is expecting a list of List<UserInfo> which has not been passed and the null reference occured.
While I was trying to reproduced your issue I found that, within Apply action method you are not populating any list of users so getting following error for that:

How to fix:
In order to fix your exception, you should pass your userList to that view. What you could do as following:
Repository:
public class Repository
{
    private static List<UserInfo> _users = new();

    public static List<UserInfo> Users
    {
        get
        {
            return _users;
        }
    }

    static Repository()
    {
        _users.Add(new UserInfo() { Id = 1, Name = "Busra", Email = "blablabla@gmail.com", Phone = "111111111", WillAttend = true });
        _users.Add(new UserInfo() { Id = 2, Name = "Nur", Email = "blablabla@gmail.com", Phone = "8384388438", WillAttend = true });
        _users.Add(new UserInfo() { Id = 3, Name = "Busra", Email = "blablabla@gmail.com", Phone = "3438848384", WillAttend = true });
    }

}

Controller:
So, fetch your user list from your repository as your repositoty has Users collection.   You could write as following
public IActionResult Apply()
 {

     var _listOfUsers = Repository.Users;
     return View(_listOfUsers);
 }

Note: I have founded another issue in your repository where you have static repository initialization of _users.Add(new KullaniciBilgi() which is incorrect. It should be _users.Add(new UserInfo() according to your UserInfo class. Above steps would resolve your issue.
Output:


